# sharepoint mysite authentication

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication, aspnetdb, mysite, sql-authentication

I have created mysite and two other sites as 3 different web applications in my sharepoint server like

```
http://site1.sp.com:45 - site 1
http://site2.sp.com:45 - site 2
http://mysite.sp.com:45 - mysite site
```

all sites are using authentication  (`aspnetdb`)

each sites ( site1 and site 2) got different content and different users , these all user have their mysite in

mysite.sp.com web application .so when users want to go to mysite i am redirecting to the mysite.sp.com site and it asking again authentication for user.  i need to have mysite in a separate web application.

I have added `http://*.sp.com` into intranet zone in ie.but still mysite prompt login page.

So is there any solution to get mysite authentication working ..

please suggest me..